# Need URL Rewrite to replace a string in a url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am looking and looking and coming up with all different patterns, but no such luck. I require a rewrite rule to handle the a replacement of a string xyzlisting with xyz-listing. It may be anywhere in the url. Is there a straightforward way to write this rule?

Comment: Which server are you using? Is it Apache? Are you talking about mod_rewrite? Can you show us some example?

Comment: Sorry about that. IIS Url Rewrite. Really, just direct entry into web.config file.

Comment: An example: www.mydomain.com/xyzlisting/... to go to www.mydomain.com/xyz-listing/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so experienced with IIS. However, I can suggest something:

In Apache mod_rewrite, you can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)(/\w+)(listing)(.*)$ $1$2-$3$4
```

This rule will split whatever string in the format anything followed by 'listing' that comes after mydomain.com/ with a '-'. Which results in 'anything-listing', wherever in the URL.

This will only change the last occurrence of this type of string. It will not replace more than one occurrence.

You can import this URl rewrite rule from Apache to IIS using this IIS extension:

[IIS Extenson page for url rewrite  module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am SO unfamiliar with mod_rewrite, but I'll try and import this rule and see what it does. Thank you!

Comment: So all i have to do here is change the '3' depending on where i want the string to split?  And, in this case, this string always has to come right after the domain name?

Comment: Yes. You have to change the number of \w s inorder to fix the number of characters to the left. The rule splits only the string which comes right after the domain name. All other strings will remain the same.
Is this what you want? Or do you want to split the string before the word 'listing' ?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like for the word 'xyzlisting' to be replaceable regardless of where it occurs in the url.

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*)(\w\w\w)(listing)(.*)$ $1$2-$3$4`
This rule will replace xyzlisting to xyz-listing wherever in the URL. But, it will not replace more than one occurrence. It will only replace the last occurrence.
For ex, **mydomain.com/xyzlisting/xyzlisting** will be replaced by **mydomain.com/xyzlisting/xyz-listing**

Comment: I will only have one occurrence. But where is it referencing the whole word "xyzlisting"?  Let's say I had abcdlisting?

Comment: Here we go then : `RewriteRule (.*)(/\w+)(listing)(.*)$ $1$2-$3$4`
I have edited the answer accordingly.